# Ajax TabContainer change body background color

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I am trying to change the style of tab body in `TabContainer`, without changing any other style. So basically I am trying to change the default style of `TabContainer` ie  `ajax__tab_xp` so this i have tried so far.

```
.ajax__tab_xp .ajax__tab_body
 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-top: 0;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

but the style is not changing.

Comment: hvae u  use jquery library ? and plz show your html/.net code also.its not a big problem :)

Comment: The default out of the box id for the Ajax tab container's body is `tabcontainer_body` if I remember rightly, not the class `ajax__tab_body` you specify above, unless of course you've changed it's name in the asp.net code? All hit alt + f5 just in case the cache hasn't updated.

Comment: All other style like ajax__tab_tab is working fine..

Comment: Here looks like a list of all of them: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/act_TabContainer.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like embedded styles link included after your custom css stylesheet. You might specify `CssClass` property for TabContainer and use it in your stylesheet or add `!important` modifier to rules those you want to override.